# Angular 8. Template driven form element conditional required attribute

Tags: angular

I guess it is a very dumb question. I have input element (type='text') that should have *required* attribute conditionally. My code looks like:

```
<input type="text" [attr.required]="required ? '' : null"
```

and I clearly observe that *required* attribute is present inside HTML DOM while inspecting output in Browser.

[image]

But for some reason *required* attribute doesn't work inside my form validation (field always have ng-valid class).

Meanwhile if I add *required* attribute brutally (unconditionally, as an ordinary html layout) like:

```
<input type="text" required
```

then it works for me: *ng-valid* class is removed automatically if field is empty.

What I do wrong with `[attr.required]="required ? '' : null"`  ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you tried using [attr.required]="'!required'" remember to put it inside single quote

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta - unfortunatelly, it doesn't work in single quotes or without them :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use it like this:
`[required]="isFieldRequired() ? 'required' : null"`